# How to add a uid to html nodes?

Tags: text-generation

I have a giant html file which is a mess (not my fault). I want to add to some nodes (about 400) a unique id. They all have are of the same class, so I can add the id like this

```
:% s/class="some-class"/& id=<some id>/
```

My problem is generating the id - its has to be unique for each match.

Any ideas?

Comment: Note that this strategy may fail if any of those nodes already has an id, particularly an id supplied after the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you use the expression replacement (`:help sub-replace-expression`) and a simple counter function? Something like

```
function! MyCount()
    if exists('w:count')
        let w:count = w:counter + 1
    else 
        let w:count = 1
    endif
    return w:count
endfunc

:%s/class="some-class"/\=submatch(0) . ' "id"="' . MyCount() . '"'/
:unlet w:counter
```

Assuming the id attribute and value should both be enclosed in quotes.

`submatch()` is similar to `\0` in the replacement, but plays well with in an expression replacement (see `:help submatch()`).

Comment: That would give a invalid `id`, [ref](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name). Perhaps something like `return printf('foo%03d', w:count)` if one want to get fancy.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the solution given by @jjaderberg, on Linux systems you can get a uuid with the command

```
uuidgen
```

A solution could be to use the following one liner:

```
%s/class="some-class"/\=submatch(0) . ' id=' . system('uuidgen')/
```

To get this kind of result:

```
class="some-class" id=db2c6d1c-4646-4998-bec8-c697e5bc668c
```

This clearly isn't the best solution (I think jjaderbeg's one is far better), but I think the idea to add the result of an external command in a substitution can *(sometimes)* be interesting .

Comment: Eeek! If you're going to rely on external facilities anyway, use the `uuidgen` command. Simpler, part of `util-linux`, so highly likely to be installed anyway.